# 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;..." Python MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, salesforce, mysql-python

So I have been working on this since last Friday and cannot get around this error:

> 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '[u'161010-035670'] WHERE order_id=87' at line 1" or something
>   along the same lines as this error.

Basically my python will grab data from MySQL database, it creates a case in SalesForce using Simple-Salesforce and then queries that case it created correctly but I need it to write that case number back into the database in a column I created specifically for the ticket number.

Current Code:

```
for rowx in xrange(1, sheet.nrows):
    SN = sheet.row_values(rowx, start_colx=3, end_colx=None)[0]
    print SN
    Id = sheet.row_values(rowx, start_colx=6, end_colx=None)[0]
    print Id
    d = sf.query("SELECT CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE Serial_Number__c ='%s' AND Status = 'New Portal RMA'" % SN)

    data = [e["CaseNumber"] for e in d["records"]]
    print (data)



    try:
        con = MySQLdb.connect(user=ur, passwd=pd, host=ht, port=pt, db=db)
        cursor = con.cursor()

        cursor.execute("UPDATE rma_order SET rma_num=%s WHERE order_id=%s" % (data, Id))

        con.commit()
    except Error as error:
        print(error)

    finally:
        cursor.close()
        con.close()
```

Main issue is with this line of code:

```
 cursor.execute("UPDATE rma_order SET rma_num=%s WHERE order_id=%s" % (data, Id))
```

I have tried with and without '%s' with no difference, tried "...WHERE order_id=%s", (data, Id))   with same error. If I replace "order_id=87" and let data stay there with cursor.execute("UPDATE rma_order SET rma_num=%s WHERE order_id=87" % (data))     then it works fine and writes the case number in the correct format into the database, as soon as I add "Id" as a factor with %s then it gives me errors. I have also tried with %d with same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `data` value is a *list* and you are trying to format it into the query. And, **don't use string formatting to insert variables into a query** - use a proper *query parameterization* instead:

```
cursor.execute("""
    UPDATE 
        tplinkus_rma.rma_order 
    SET 
        rma_num=%s 
    WHERE 
       order_id=%s""", (data[0], Id))
```

Note how the query parameters are placed in a tuple and passed as a separate argument.

Comment: Man.... I spent over 10 hours on this trying different methods and you resolve it in all of the amount of time it took you to hit "Add Comment". Thank you alecxe