# Simple "CREATE" or "DROP TABLE" fails with PyMySQL and parameter replacement

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm basically using the following code to drop an existing table using Python 3.6 and PyMySQL, with a MySQL 5.7 database:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(
    host=host,
    user=username,
    password=password,
    db=database,
    charset='utf8mb4',
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
)

table_name = "video_playback_statistics"
sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s"
params = (table_name,)

with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

I get the following error:

> pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''video_playback_statistics'' at line 1"

I've successfully executed other, more complicated SQL statements with more parameters, but this simple one does not work.

When I run the SQL command without parametrization, it works fine:

```
cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS video_playback_statistics')
```

I've looked at the following questions:

- [1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;..." Python MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39965697/1064-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax-python-mysql)
- [pymysql return error SQL syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47730967/pymysql-return-error-sql-syntax)

But these kinds of queries seem to work fine.

Also I've seen this:

- [Python MYSQL update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307378/python-mysql-update-statement)

But here the table name is directly written into the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the parametrization of table names or column names is not possible, according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424918/mysql-query-with-python-all-variables?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment70055456_41424918). The adapter, for some reason, inserts two double quotes for the value, which causes a syntax error.

Two possible solutions would be:

1. Use backslash escaping for the parameter:

   ```
   sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `%s`"
   ```
2. Use Python string formatting:

   ```
   sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {}".format(table_name)
   ```

For values (e.g. in `INSERT` or `WHERE` statements), you should still use parametrization.